# does phonegap support RSSI reporting for blue tooth low energy?

Tags: cordova

I can't seem to find any mention of RSSI reporting in the phonegap docs. Does this mean I have to resort to native code?

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a Bluetooth Low Energy [plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE) for PhoneGap that supports both Android and iOS. I forgot to include this in the documentation, but the scan result objects contain an rssi field. It doesn't currently support reading the RSSI from a connected device, but that's something I can add pretty easily if requested.